# Get values of different class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a little problem with my code.

I have two classes A and B. Class A is generating a list with a dynamic number of class B instances. for example:

```
class A:
    listTest = []
    def Foo(self):
        for i in range (5):
            self.listTest.append(B())

class B:
    def Bar (self):
        status = A.listTest[3]
```

Now I need in class B some information about other instances of the same class or rather information about other listTest-entries of this class-A-Instance.

Is there any way to do that?

I've tried allready with a get function to return a special value but this won't work.

Comment: Note that listTest is part of class A, not its instances. You can access it directly via the class.

Comment: I want to access the list out of class B. e.g. in A.listTest are 5 class-B-objects. I want to acces the second B-object from the fifth one

Comment: That is pretty much what you are doing already. `B().Bar()` successfully accesses the fourth `B` instance (provided that `A().Foo()` was called to create it first, of course). Please clarify what error you are getting, or in how far the behaviour does not match your expectation. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to do something like this?

```
class A:
    list_test = []
    def foo(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.list_test.append(B())

class B:
    def bar(self, A_instance):
        status = A_instance.list_test[3]
        return status


A_instance = A()
A_instance.foo()

B_instance = B()
print(B_instance.bar(A_instance))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `A.Foo` method, you are populating the object's (`self`) copy of the class-level variable `listTest`. So, inside class `B`, you need to initialize an instance of class `A` to call `Foo` and populate the list. For example,

```
class B:
    def Bar (self):
        a = A()
        a.Foo()
        status = a.listTest[3]
```

should give you a hint.

Your current implement would raise an `IndexError`, while you'll be accessing `A.listTest[3]` as `A.listTest` is an empty list. You need to populate the list by calling `Foo()` on an instance of `A`, as i've done.